# No callback results returned

Tags: python, twisted

I have a minimal script that uses twisted backend to return the GET request from yahoo finance. However, nothing is returned to the console but the code runs successfully. Am I missing something here. How do I get a successful returned result?

```
import asyncio
from collections import namedtuple
from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor
asyncioreactor.install()
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer, task
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
from twisted.web.client import Agent

#Using the above then create an async reactor HTTP request
headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com',
    'Referer': 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EFTMC?p=%5EFTMC',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.4 Safari/605.1.15',
}

url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=^FTMC&fields=exchangeTimezoneName,exchangeTimezoneShortName,regularMarketTime,gmtOffSetMilliseconds&region=GB&lang=en-GB'

class asyncHTTP:
    def __init__(self,method, url, headers):
        self._method = method
        self._url = url
        self._headers = headers
        self._agent = Agent(reactor)

    @staticmethod
    def R(response):
        O = namedtuple('Response', ['code', 'headers', 'body', 'content'])
        finished = defer.Deferred()
        return finished.addCallback(O(response.code,
            response.headers,
            response.body,
            response.content))

    async def cbRequest(self):
        r = await self._agent.request(
            self._method.encode('utf-8'),
            self._url.encode('utf-8'),
            Headers(self._headers),
            None
        )
        return r.addCallback(self.R)

async def main(twist):
    return await twist.cbRequest()

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    tw = asyncHTTP('Get', url, headers)
    asyncio.run(main(tw))
```

Comment: What output are you expecting to see in the console?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
if '__name__' == '__main__':
```

To

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

This still reveals your program has an error

```
RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <Deferred at 0x7f75a50e3d30>
```

But it answers why you are not seeing any output.